# Canvas accessing coordinate of translated position of panning background image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Cannot figure this out, how to find the translated position of the background relative to the canvas. I have the characters coordinates, and I have the coordinates from a mouse click within the canvas, but can't figure out how to find the offset.

In the canvas, when I click somewhere, I get an (x,y) value from (0,0) - (650,575), the size of the window, no matter where my character is. If the character is at (2000, 1500) on the canvas, my click/touch input will always send the character up and left towards 0,0 on the background coordinate.

At first I thought I should subtract the player X position from the max width, then add an offset half the width of the screen, and do the same for the Y position, but that didn't work.

Then I tried subtracting half the width/height of the screen from the current player x,y values but that doesn't work.

Anyone point me in the right direction, it seems elementary but I can't figure it out it's been years since math class???? Thanks

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 650;
canvas.height = 575;
var WIDTH=5000;  //level width
var HEIGHT=3750; //level height
ctx.translate(-WIDTH*.5,-HEIGHT*.5); //starts in center of background
```

Where my player begins on load:

```
hero.x = WIDTH*.5+325; //offset half canvas width
hero.y = HEIGHT*.5+275; //offset half canvas height
```

For the Background:

```
ctx.drawImage(bgImage,  BGsrcX , BGsrcY, 1250 , 938 ,-150, -150, BGdestW, BGdestH); `//image is stretched to 5000x3750`
```

This is the mouse input I'm using

```
  if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone)|(iPod)|(iPad)/i)){
   document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
      if(e.touches.length == 1){ // Only deal with one finger
           var touch = e.touches[0]; // Get the information for finger #1
                var x = touch.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                var y = touch.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
                //clickEvent(x,y); //call your function to manage tweets
            }
        },false);
     }
    else{
        document.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) {
            var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
            console.log(x+":"+y);
            clickEvent(x,y); //call your function to manage tweets
        },false);
    }
```

For the keyboard input to actually pan the background:

```
if(16 in keysDown && 38 in keysDown && hero.y > 200) {ctx.translate(0,12); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't work with half-translated and non-translated coordinates, translate your mouse click coordinates AND your canvas coordinates.

Then you can just use simple subtraction to find the offset, and to find the distance, you you use the distance formula.

Comment: Not sure I follow how to translate the mouse click. Movement has been with the keyboard and Im now trying to switch to mouse. Currently when an arrow key is moved, it translates the background either translate(0,12) or translate(0,-12) to go back and forth

Comment: You translate it the same way you're translating the canvas coordinates and with the same shift. So, if you're translating the canvas from (0, 0) to (50, 50), do the same for the mouse!

Comment: Also the other problem I was hoping to solve by having a point of reference is when you get to the edge of the background, you can translate the view area beyond the background...I don't know how to access the currently translated location to put it in an if(location > maxwidthallowed) {dont allow translate}     Say I want to translate between 0 and 5000 pixels but not more than 5000 pixels on the x axis?

Comment: Okay, so, when you initialize the canvas, save the width and height of the canvas, and that's your limiting factor to when you translate.

Comment: I have var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 650;
canvas.height = 575;                                 And that's what pans the 5000x3750 background image         can I access it's x and y values somehow?

Comment: You're right, sorry I can't upvote you because I don't have 15 rating but you're right. I increment the .offsetLeft and .offsetTop to adjust the mouse around the character...Thank you.